# Category and URL problem

Tags: url, categories

In my url the entry have a category and a sub-category.

1. Category = meat
2. sub category = beef

> href="{url}/{channel_short_name}/{categories}{category_url_title}{/categories}/{url_title}"

I'm using {category_url_title}, but the result URL is:

```
mysite/recipes/meatbeef/hamburger
```

The category and the sub category are together: **meatbeef** with no /. It should be **meat/beef**.

How to have a category and subcategories working fine, like : cat/subcat/subsubcat..??
It give me headaches :)

Happy XMas
Stéphane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [backspace](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/categories.html#backspace) parameter:

```
href="{url}/{channel_short_name}/{categories backspace='1'}{category_url_title}/{/categories}/{url_title}"
```

Backspace removes x characters from the final output.

Watch out if your entry belongs to 1 or more sub categories as your category URLs will grow uncontrollably.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! I tried to put a /, the categories was divided by a /, but // in the front. I didn't know the backspace parameter.